# How to count number of emails in a message field in logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash-grok

> "2019-07-26T16:04:56.760Z,10.155.61.162,citymail4exedge,10.141.6.34,CSMAIL-DR.NYC.GOV,08D70FED2805DAAC;250 2.6.0  [InternalId=54732279] Queued mail for delivery,to CS,SMTP,SEND,446859,,phonebook@acs.nyc.gov;vincent.fox@acs.nyc.gov,250 2.1.5 Recipient OK;250 2.1.5 Recipient OK,2697,2,,;,ACS Telephone Directory Personal Information Update Request,phonebook@acs.nyc.gov,phonebook@acs.nyc.gov,2019-07-26T16:04:56.119Z;SRV=citymail4exedge.nycnet:TOTAL=0,Originating,,,\r"

```
(?<emailuser1>[\w.]+)\@(?<domain1>\w+\.\w+\.\w+)(\.\w+)?
```

I have used this logstash grok pattern to separate the email and domain separately and need to have the count of them in logstash.

```
  "phonebook"
```

"domain1":

```
  "acs.nyc.gov"
```

"emailuser2:

```
  "vincent.fox"
```

"domain2": 
    [
      "acs.nyc.gov"

Answer (score 0):

If you're only interested by the number of emails, you can just count the number of **@**.

```
filter {
  mutate {
    add_field => ["count"]
  }

  ruby {
    code => "count = message.count(\"@\")"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can do that in grok, but you can do it in ruby.

```
    ruby {
        init => '
            EMAIL = /(([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_\.\+\-=:]+)@\b((?:[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62})(?:\.(?:[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62}))*(\.?|\b)))/
        '
        code => '
            matches = event.get("message").scan(EMAIL)
            local = []
            domain = []
            address = []
            matches.each { |x|
                unless address.include? x[0]
                    address << x[0]
                    local << x[1]
                    domain << x[2]
                end
            }
            domain.each_index { |x|
                event.set("domain#{x+1}", domain[x])
            }
            local.each_index { |x|
                event.set("emailuser#{x+1}", local[x])
            }
#                event.set("user", local)
#                event.set("domain", domain)
        '
    }
```

The regexp for an email is based on the grok pattern, not yours.